Ubuntu 24.04 - syslog is full of gdm-x-session messages
I have installed (clean installation to new disk) Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on my miniPC. Monitor (TV) is connected via HDMI.
I have noticed that syslog is full of following messages - and new set of the same messages is coming every second.
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 0
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1360x768"x0.0   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 776 798 -hsync -vsync>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1094 1125 interla>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interla>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   74.25  1920 2558 2602 2750  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x576i"x0.0   27.00  1440 1464 1590 1728  576 580 586 625 interlace -h>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x480i"x0.0   27.00  1440 1478 1602 1716  480 488 494 525 interlace -h>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync>
    ... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1568]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz

There was no problem on the same PC with Ubuntu 22.04 and earlier. Does somebody here knows what does it mean and how to fix it?
